# Placing Camera at different positions in world space

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera, mesh, glm-math

Is there a way to manipulate the field of view of camera when the camera is at 2 different positions in world space?

For example, In the first position, multiple mesh parts are transformed in different directions across the origin(where the camera looks at) until they form one mesh. This is done by calling glm::translate(), glm::rotate(), e.t.c before loading the vertices in the vbo.

In the second position, I want to transform the whole mesh (from above). Since I already loaded everything needed into the vbo and my models are drawn, I can't draw my new transformed mesh. Is there a way to draw my new transformed mesh without loading vertices into the vbo again?

And, if I have to load my vbo again, how do I go about it, since loading the vbo is dependent on how many parts the mesh is divided into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the vertex data into VBOs and transforming them has *nothing* to do with each other - stuff like `glm::translate()` or `glm::rotate` will not have any influence on the buffer contents - the only change some matrix. As long as *you* do not apply some transformation do you vertex data when you upload it to the buffer, no one else does. Typicalle, those transformation matrices are used when *drawing* the objects (by the vertex shader, on the GPU), so one can have moving objects and a moving camera without having to respecify the geometry data.

So in your case, it will be enough to just change the projection and view matrices and draw the obnjects again with those new matrices applied.

Comment: Good explanation about the vbos, but I created the new projection and view matrices and it still didn't work was why I thought I needed to do something with the vbos. What I did was after the mesh is drawn, I call glm::rotate and friends with the values that would transform the whole thing, then I send the multiplication of the projection and view matrices to the shader. Is that the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. GL is a _state machine_. Just setting new matrices for the shaders is not enough - the shaders are invoked via a _draw call_. So you have to first set the matrices you want to draw with, and then redraw, so that the newly set matrices can have any effect. The GL is not a scene graph API, it does not remember waht objects are in your scene, it is just a render API, and you have to tell it what to render, and how to.

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver. :)